# Mongoose - modifiedpaths not identifying array field as modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var Person = new Schema({
persondetails: {
 name: {
    type: String,
    uppercase: true,
    required: true
 },
 nationalities: [ {
    nationality : String
 }]
});
```

and a presave function to check modified paths:

```
schema
.pre('save', function(next) {
    var document = this;
    _.each(document.modifiedPaths(), function(path) {
        console.log(path);
    });
    return next();
});
```

if i do:

```
new Person({persondetails: {
                   name: 'Some Name',
                   nationalities: [ {nationality: 'Some Country'}]
           }
)
```

Or even pick an already existing 'Person' and add a new element to its nationalities array,

presaved hook prints:

```
persondetails
persondetails.name
persondetails.nationalities
```

But i was expecting the 'persondetails.nationalities.0.nationality' as well.

Is this expected behavior or am i missing something ?